# outline to implement http://thecoloradan.com/ like navbar. i'm not asking how to implement this.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this website [1]: http://thecoloradan.com/ has a beautiful navbar which upon loading of the webpage looks like as if it is merged with the background and upon scrolling shifts to the top of the page and remains there. and all this happens with a nice animation. all i want to know is the outline that i can use to implement this. further help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
[the coloradan home page][1]

Comment: check the **html**, **javascript** and **css** for [this page](http://thecoloradan.com/) to get an outline of how to implement such a navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two classes, one for the transparent one, and one for the one that shows when you scroll. Using JavaScript, you can detect the scroll event and switch the classes.

Here is an example.

```js
// Uses jQuery.

function updateNavbar() {
    var scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scroll > 0) {
        $('.navbar').addClass("navbar-light");
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-light");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        updateNavbar();
    });

    updateNavbar();
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: gray;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.15s ease all;
  transition: 0.08s ease height line-height;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: white;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-light a {
  color: black;
}

.fill-space {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">

  <span>Navbar</span>
  
  <span class="fill-space"></span>
  
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

If you are into building websites, I would highly recommend you learn [Bootstrap v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com). It is very useful and makes it so much easier.

Comment: @sarj7 If you want an updated version for Bootstrap, just ask!

Comment: i tried really hard to mobile optimize this sample navbar but am struggling to do so.

Comment: a schematic representation using the afore mentioned code would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a big in height navbar with transparent background, which when users scrolls the website, it changes two properties: background color and height. You should look at [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event. If you tell me more about the technologies you use (e.g. Bootstrap), I could provide more details on how to achieve this.

Comment: yeah i use bootstrap and all the web related framework like javascript, jquery